# golang mongo-db transaction cannot create namespace

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to do db transaction with mongo-db in golang but getting cannot create namespace error

```
    // For a replica set, include the replica set name and a seedlist of the members in the URI string; e.g.
    // uri := "mongodb://mongodb0.example.com:27017,mongodb1.example.com:27017/?replicaSet=myRepl"
    // For a sharded cluster, connect to the mongos instances; e.g.
    // uri := "mongodb://mongos0.example.com:27017,mongos1.example.com:27017/"
    uri := "mongodb://mongo-0/block-recorder?replicaSet=rs0"
    // var uri string

    clientOpts := options.Client().ApplyURI(uri)
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOpts)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer func() { _ = client.Disconnect(ctx) }()

    // Prereq: Create collections.
    wcMajority := writeconcern.New(writeconcern.WMajority(), writeconcern.WTimeout(1*time.Second))
    wcMajorityCollectionOpts := options.Collection().SetWriteConcern(wcMajority)
    blockCollection := client.Database("block-recorder").Collection("Block", wcMajorityCollectionOpts)

    // Step 1: Define the callback that specifies the sequence of operations to perform inside the transaction.
    callback := func(sessCtx mongo.SessionContext) (interface{}, error) {
        // Important: You must pass sessCtx as the Context parameter to the operations for them to be executed in the
        // transaction.
        dbBlock := model.TransferBlockData(block)
        if _, err := blockCollection.InsertOne(sessCtx, dbBlock); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return nil, nil
    }

    // Step 2: Start a session and run the callback using WithTransaction.
    session, err := client.StartSession()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer session.EndSession(ctx)

    result, err := session.WithTransaction(ctx, callback)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("result: %v\n", result)
```

This is the sample code I am using, Getting below error

```
panic: multiple write errors: [{write errors: [{Cannot create namespace block-recorder.Block in multi-document transaction.}]}, {<nil>}]
```

I uses gorm most of the times, This is my first time using mongo with golang, It says create collection first which I am already doing ? Is there any other method to create collection for mongo in golang ?
How to do a proper transaction with struct data example ?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB server cannot currently create collections in a transaction.

If your application is, say, inserting data into a collection that doesn't exist, the server transparently creates the collection in most cases. But this does not work currently if a transaction is active.

Create the collection ahead of time so that it exists by the time the transaction is executing.

Instantiating a collection object in your application does not actually create a collection. To create a collection, try the equivalent of [createCollection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/) in the go driver.

Comment: I have same issue as well, do u have example how to createCollection like that link ? in go mongo driver just do `client.Database('name').Collection('collections')`, I have no idea createCollection in Go